# Spanning class of derived category of right modules over a noncommutative algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

It is known that if $X$ is smooth projective over a field, then the collection $\mathcal{O}_x$ with $x$ a closed point of $X$ form a spanning class for $D^b(X)$.

Now suppose $X=Spec R$ for some noetherian ring $R$ and $A$ be a (noncommutative) algebra over $R$. Let $D^b(A)$ be the bounded derived category of right $A$-modules.

My question is: Is there a nice spanning for $D^b(A)$ like in the first paragraph?

p.s: I would very much appreciate it if someone can recommend some reference for generalities on $D^b(A)$.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If $A$ is locally free of finite rank as an $R$-module, then $\{A_x\}_{x \in X}$ is a spanning class.

Comment: The appendix B of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0503700.pdf has a good deal of material on $D^b(X,A)$ when $A$ is a sheaf of Azumaya algebras. Many results in this appendix do generealize for any sheaf of algebras. 

If you have a specific example in mind, it would be easier to say something about a spanning class for $D^b(X,A)$.